# How to use Parse iOS SDK to create service for other developers?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to build a SDK that developers could integrate with their apps that would use my own backend.

Thinking of using parse open source as a platform I could wrap around to build my service.

I'm looking for the best way to do that with the following requirements:

1. Wrapping parse iOS SDK in a way I would still be able to update easily (pulling new changes without having complex mechanisms/changes to make inside the SDK).
2. I want my SDK to co-exist with other developer SDK even if he use parse iOS SDK himself. So I could put my server parameters and developer can put his and it won't collide.

Is there a way to do that? What is the best practice?

Comment: When you initialize the Parse instance in your app you supply an endpoint and an API key. If you supplied those pieces then someone can connect to your service. If you want to add functionality to the existing Parse SDK I think a category or subclass would be the way to go.

Comment: @DanSpiteri That's right. But issue is the app that integrate my SDK (parse based) could himself using parse with his code. Then his API keys would overwrite mine or the opposite way. This is a problem.
I thought someone has something better than changing/rewrite (in a way) the whole parse SDK to support this.